# Magento Mobile Shoppe Theme onepage checkout not working on CE 1.8

Tags: magento, mobile, magento-1.8

I'm having a real issue with the checkout as I'm stuck on step 3 Shipping Method.

One thing I noticed that "Your Checkout Process" on the right hand side doesn't load content.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here i posted your second question answer for checkout progress disappeared backward one by one.

look for the code in your frontend/default/theme/layout/checkout.xml

```
    <checkout_onepage_progress>
            <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
            <remove name="right"/>
            <remove name="left"/>

            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
                <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_info" name="payment_info">
                    <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </checkout_onepage_progress>
```

Change it to this

```
<checkout_onepage_progress>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
            <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="billing.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml"></block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shipping.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml"></block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shippingmethod.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml"></block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="payment.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/payment.phtml"></block>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_progress>

    <!-- Individual blocks for Progress steps begins -->
    <checkout_onepage_progress_billing>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml">
            <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_progress_billing>


    <checkout_onepage_progress_shipping>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml">
            <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_progress_shipping>


    <checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml">
            <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method>

    <checkout_onepage_progress_payment>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress/payment.phtml">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_info" name="payment_info">
            <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
        </block>
        <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
    </block>
    </checkout_onepage_progress_payment>
```

I hope this will resolve your issue please comment & feedback!!

Comment: Perfect Sanjay Patel. Thank you. This works on my FireFox now.

Comment: This also seems to be a problem in `magento-1.9.2.2.tar-2015-10-27-03-19-32\app\design\frontend\default\modern\layout\checkout.xml` here is a diff file to fix it on that one: http://pastebin.com/MNWbuiXE

Answer (score 4):

i will try again since my last post was deleted.
There is two steps you need to take in order to get Mobileshoppe back working again:

**1.**
Go to /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml

and change this (line 36 for me)

```
<fieldset>
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

to this

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

**2.**
Open app/design/frontend/default/mobileshoppe/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml

Find this line:

```
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder') ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```

and change it to

```
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```

This is the new way on how the order is processed/posted/saved.
Probably this might be helpful for other people aswell that are stuck on the onepage checkout after upgrade/update to Magento 1.8.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much Marcel. Your fixes got me pass all the steps and completed my order. One more help please. How can I make the right hand side tab "Your Checkout Process" work? e.g showing the steps. Currently it just collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

I hope im not doing something wrong by posting another answer for your second question. i have worked on the checkout progress thing too but it is not 100% perfect. See if this works for you:

***1.*** Open the file app/design/frontend/default/mobileshoppe/layout/checkout.xml

***2.***
Search for this line:

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="checkout.progress" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml"/>
```

***3.***
Replace it with the following:

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="checkout.progress" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="billing.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml"></block>
    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shipping.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml"></block>
    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shippingmethod.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml"></block>
    <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="payment.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/payment.phtml"></block>
</block>
```

Comment: Thank you very much again Marcel. I've done what you advised. Initially, it loaded all 4 steps: Billing Address, Shipping Address, Shipping Method, Payment Method. However, when I moved down the order to complete my order, the steps on the right hand side disappeared backward one by one till not showing anything at all when I was in step Order Review.

Comment: Hi user2781012, i noticed this - i also noticed that the progress links are not clickable. For me this is ok as it is right now so i won't further investigate. But maybe you can help yourself. Try comparing the mobileshoppe skin files with the current default theme files from Magento 1.8. Some things have changed and the default theme has them. But ofcourse our custom themes do not. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Marcel. I compared & found the col-right was required for the progress box to show. Now I settled for 1 column layout for the onepage checkout.

Comment: I just updated to magento-1.9.2.2 and had this problem. It looks like the official `magento-1.9.2.2.tar-2015-10-27-03-19-32\app\design\frontend\default\modern\layout\checkout.xml` is also missing those blocks. So even the stock modern frontend and themes basen on it are broken.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with Magento 1.8.1.0. I solved it by this

1. Open app/design/frontend/default/mobileshoppe/layout/checkout.xml
2. Change the line

   ```
                  <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
   ```

   To

   ```
                  <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/info.phtml">
   ```

Good luck!